# How do I extract the last two items from the list, strings or tuples in Python?

Tags: python, slice

User will input the string, list or tuples.

I have to extract the first do and the last two values. For the first two values:

```
ls[:2]
```

For the last two values how can I do it?

If `n` is the total number of values the last two item can be sliced as:

```
[n-1:]
```

How can I put down in the code?

Answer (score 25):

```
ls[-2:]
```

Negative numbers in slices are simply evaluated by adding `len(ls)`, so this is the same as `ls[len(ls) - 2:]`. For more information on slices, refer to the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) or [this excellent stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/35070).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was making it complicated, it's really simple! Thank you for the resources too.

Answer (score 6):

```
ls[-2:]
```

would be the way to do it, as negative indexes count from the end.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a list like this: `a_list = [1,2,3]` you can get last two `[2,3]` elements by `a_list[-2:]`